# Why does a new terminal get automatically closed?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, sudo, root

Every time I open a new terminal it gets automatically closed. I'm running Arch Linux, and Xforce4 terminal.

```
$ terminal --execute sudo arpspoof -i $(cat var.log|awk '{print $1}') \
           -t $(cat var.log|awk '{print $4}') $(cat var.log|awk '{print $3}')
```

or

```
# terminal --execute arpspoof -i $(cat var.log|awk '{print $1}') \
           -t $(cat var.log|awk '{print $4}') $(cat var.log|awk '{print $3}')
```

Error printed upon execution of either of the above commands:

```
Unable to register terminal service: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes
include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security
policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection
was broken.
```

Answer (score 0):

The "default" behavior for a terminal is to terminate when the program it has been instructed to run is finished. It does this because this is the most practical thing to do. If you wish to read the output before it disappears, consider adding a command at the end like so:

```
urxvt -e sh -c 'cowsay howdy?; sleep 1337'
```

Some terminals, such as rxvt-unicode have an option to hang around until closed by the window manager:

```
-hold|+hold
    Turn on/off hold window after exit support. If enabled, urxvt will 
    not immediately destroy its window when the program executed within 
    it exits.  Instead, it will wait till it is being killed or closed by 
    the user; resource hold.
```